# How to mock a property in Python with a **lambda**?

Tags: python, mocking

I have a property and want to mock it in a unittest:

```
class Foo:
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return random.randint()
```

But I need to define a function or lambda in the mock, since the value won't be constant
in the test. For simplicity I removed the dependency on `self.other_attribute` in the example.

I tried [PropertyMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) but could not get it working up to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need PopertyMock, if you want to use a function or lambda.

You can use `property(lambda ....)`

```
import random
from unittest.mock import patch


class Foo:
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return random.randint()

with patch('__main__.Foo.bar', property(lambda foo: ...)):
    assert Foo().bar == ...
```